# Filename with variables ( filename_L=10.mat)

Tags: matlab, save, filenames

I would like to save a workspace with the result as `14-Nov-2019_094655_script name_L10_P50.mat`.
Data and time I will add as `datestr(now, 'dd-mmm-yyyy_HHMMSS'`, but I don't know how to add a scrip name and variables in the filename.
`script_name` is the name of the script that I run, `L10_P50` are values `L` and `P`, which are changed in every run of the script. (`L10_P50` means L=10 and P=50 in this run).
how to implement it?

edit 1:

I would like to increase the resolution. For that I have written :

```
fileNamefig = [dstr, '_',flname, '_Num',  num2str(loops_num),'_N', num2str(Nfft), '.jpg'];
saveas(fig,['C:\Users\Matlab\results\fig_files\',fileNamefig])
set(fig,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
print(fig, '-djpeg','-r600','fileNamefig')
```

It dosnt work. HOw to rewrite it?

Comment: string concatenation.   `['hello_', num2str(12), '_world' ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
% your variables
L = 10;
P = 50;
% date string
dstr = datestr(now, 'dd-mmm-yyyy_HHMMSS');
% file name
flname = mfilename;
% cancatanate all strings together
matname = [dstr, '_',flname, '_L',  num2str(L),'_P', num2str(P), '.mat'];
% save finally
save(matname)
```

'''